# How do I redirect a URL with a parameter to a clean URL in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am attempting to 301 redirect several URLs with parameters at the end to clean URLs.

For example I am trying to redirect:
http://example.com/news/news.php?id=1234
to
http://example.com/posts/vanity-url.php

Here is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1234
RewriteRule ^news/news\.php$ /posts/vanity-url.php [L,R=301]
```

I feel like I'm close with this code but it redirects me to:
http://example.com/posts/vanity-url.php?id=1234 and I'm not sure why this is happening.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add question sign after to remove query string

```
RewriteRule ^news/news\.php$ /posts/vanity-url.php? [L,R=301]
```